# YouTube cartoon shorts about a Latin American girl making video blogs in her room about her wanting to be an explorer

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

A few years back I watched a few shorts on YouTube about this upcoming cartoon. It was a pilot, so the few episodes are limited to the main character's room. She is a girl who started a blog that's about her dream to become an explorer. She talks about her everyday life and sometimes with her friends outside the window.

I think it was set in a post-apocalyptic world, because the girl talked about the important duty of exploring the world and finding lost knowledge from the old times. And in the last short, she gets the explorer job/title and finally leaves the village, but something bad happens to one of her girlfriends.

I think that maybe the pilot didn't get enough support and this project was abandoned. A shame, because the world and character seemed interesting and I would really like to rewatch the shorts.

I think it was called something like 'Annabelle's Blog/Diary' or something similar. And obviously it has nothing to do with *Dora the Explorer*.

Comment: Are there any Science Fiction or Fantasy  elements?

Comment: @Spencer You mean besides the mention of it being a post apocalyptic world?

Comment: Dora the explorer in the terminator franchise?

Comment: Amphibia? The Owl House?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it! [Recorded by Arizal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJ5rQvaOICI) is a 4 episodes long prelude on [Rooster Teeth](https://roosterteeth.com/series/recorded-by-arizal).
[image]

I got most of the things right, Arizal lives in the futuristic city of Maktaba and aspired to become a Record Keeper. She starts a series of vlogs talking about exploring the outside world and pondering whether she is ready to do it.

[Premise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recorded_by_Arizal)

> The series follows the story of Arizal, a 16-year-old Pinoy girl and
> straight A student who is about to pursue her desired career, to
> become a Record Keeper. The question remains if she can leave Maktaba,
> a cloistered city-state, and create records in the wide world. Through
> a set of vlogs, she ponders whether she can undertake this task, as
> part of this entry of self-discovery, and head into the world,
> explaining life beyond the city's limits to those living within the
> city. Arizal serves as the protagonist and the "audience's lens into
> this world".

It seems that after 2 years there is still no update on the upcoming series and the project was canceled due to lack of support. A shame, because I can see the potential in the plot and in the character, Arizal.